# libxml2/xmllint/lxml not ignoring whitespace when validating xsd:int

Tags: python, xml, validation, xsd

The following python script contains a simple XML schema defining an element 'a' of integer type and an XML document containing such an element. When validating the document against the schema the validation fails.

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(etree.parse(StringIO('''\
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:schema>
''')))

xmldoc = etree.parse(StringIO("<a> 42</a>"))

print xmlschema.validate(xmldoc)
```

The same failure happens when using xmllint to validate:

```
$ xmllint --schema test_schema.xml test_doc.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a> 42</a>
test_doc.xml:1: element a: Schemas validity error : Element 'a': ' 42' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:int'.
test_doc.xml fails to validate
```

According to [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition, section 4.3.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-whiteSpace) all atomic data types other than 'string' have their 'whiteSpace' constraint set to 'collapse', so the element 'a' should be valid.

Modifying the schema to explicitly set 'whiteSpace' to 'collapse' doesn't help:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:simpleType name="myint">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
      <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:element name="a" type="myint"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have found a similar issue on Stackoverflow related to the data type dateTime ([dateTime complaining about whiteSpace in XSD validation (lxml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631897/datetime-complaining-about-whitespace-in-xsd-validation-lxml)) which unfortunately has no solution.

So my questions are:

1. Should the document really validate against the given schema, or am I mistaken here?
2. Is this a known issue with libxml2? I have searched their bugzilla but didn't find anything.
3. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Update to my three questions:

1. Every information I could find makes me think that the answer is yes. And it validates successfully when using another validator.

2. I have filed a bug report for libxml2, see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726766.

3. None found so far.